# How to reshape a list in a predefined way?

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider a list (`list`) as

```
list = {{1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 
  3}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {3, 6}, {4, 3}, {4, 4}, {4, 5}, {4, 6}, {5, 
  2}, {5, 3}, {5, 4}, {5, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 2}, {6, 3}, {6, 4}, {6, 
  5}, {6, 6}, {7, 3}, {7, 4}, {7, 5}, {7, 6}, {8, 3}, {8, 4}, {8, 
  5}, {8, 6}};
```

I want to reshape this list into the following form

```
listTransformed = {{{1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}}, {{2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 
5}, {2, 6}}, {{3, 3}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {3, 6}}, {{4, 3}, {4, 4}, {4, 5}, {4,
6}}, {{5, 2}, {5, 3}, {5, 4}, {5, 5}, {5, 6}}, {{6, 2}, {6, 
3}, {6, 4}, {6, 5}, {6, 6}}, {{7, 3}, {7, 4}, {7, 5}, {7, 6}}, {{8,
3}, {8, 4}, {8, 5}, {8, 6}}};
```

The pattern is that the sublists are grouped together if their first elements are the same.

How can I do this?

Comment: `GatherBy[list, First]`?

Comment: `Values@GroupBy[list, First]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
listTransformed = GatherBy[list, First]
```